# How to detect if Image Filename has changed?

Tags: silverstripe

I need to check if the filename for my image has changed, if so then I need to update the `Slug` database field. I have tried the following within the `onBeforeWrite()` but it doesn't seem to be detecting the change..

```
<?php
class TourPhoto extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Slug' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image',
    );


    public function onBeforeWrite() {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();

        if ($this->Image()->isChanged('Name')) {
            // Update slug in here...
            $this->Slug = $this->Image()->Name;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason you're not using an Extension to add this field to `Image` directly? Or do you have more fields in `TourPhoto` that justify the DataObject wrapper?

Comment: @bummzack - I simplified the data object for example purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is your `onBeforeWrite` is called whenever `TourPhoto` is saved, not when your `Image` is saved.  `Name` is changed when `Image` is saved.

You can try two things. Add an `Image` extension with an `onBeforeWrite` in which you fetch `TourPhotos` that link to your image and update their slug.

Something like this:

```
class ImageExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $has_many = array(
        'TourPhotos' => 'TourPhoto'
    );

    public function onBeforeWrite()
    {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();

        if ($this->owner->isChanged('Name')) {
            foreach ($this->owner->TourPhotos() as $tourPhoto) {
                $tourPhoto->Slug = $this->owner->Name;
                $tourPhoto->write();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `mysite/config.yml`

```
Image:
  extensions:
    - ImageExtension
```

---

Or you could have your `TourPhoto` `onBeforeWrite` check if the slug is different from the filename and update it then.

```
class TourPhoto extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Slug' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image'
    );

    public function onBeforeWrite()
    {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();

        if ($this->Image()->exists() && $this->Slug != $this->Image()->Name) {
            $this->Slug = $this->Image()->Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the first approach is the only one that truly works, in the case you link the same image to multiple `TourPhoto` DataObjects… although it's kinda backwards to update parent properties when writing a child object.

Comment: @3dgoo - I added the ImageExtension to image, so in my `config.yml` I have done the whole `Image - Extensions - ImageExtension`, when I dev/build?flush, and load my TourPage which has a loop to loop through the TourPhotos, none of them show. So not sure whats going on there?